# Give anchor-element that has the same href-link as the Page-URL a Class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a little script and I ran into a little problem.
I want to target an `<a>` from a list which has the same href-link than the current Page-URL and give it a Class. I got the `href`-part already but I couldn't figure out how to `Tag` that specific `<a>` with a Class. Here's the code:

```js
var url = window.location.pathname; // for example /somebody
var href = $('a').attr('href');

if (url == href) {
  $('the Anchor with the right URL').addClass('myClass');
};
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/somebody">Somebody</a>
<a href="/once">Once</a>
<a href="/told">Told</a>
<a href="/me">Me</a>
```

Comment: `$('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('myClass');`

Comment: thanks everyone for the easy and fast solutions ... i think in future i will just keep asking on stackoverflow instead of searching on Google because this was like 100 times faster >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly select the correct link by using a more specialized selector. The clue is that you can select attributes as well inside it:

```js
var url = '/somebody'; //window.location.pathname; // for example /somebody
var link = $( `a[href="${ url }"]` );

if (link) link.addClass('myClass');
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/somebody">Somebody</a>
<a href="/once">Once</a>
<a href="/told">Told</a>
<a href="/me">Me</a>
```

Comment: i was searching the internet for 3 hours and didnt found a single solution ... 1 min after i posted this i allredy got the answer >.<

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over all the `<a>` element using jQuery and check the `href` attribute:

```js
var url =  '/somebody'
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href') === url){
    $(this).addClass('myClass');
  }
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/somebody">Somebody</a>
<a href="/once">Once</a>
<a href="/told">Told</a>
<a href="/me">Me</a>
```

Or you can even use a single liner using the attribute selector:

```js
var url = '/somebody'
$('a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('myClass');
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/somebody">Somebody</a>
<a href="/once">Once</a>
<a href="/told">Told</a>
<a href="/me">Me</a>
```